# Multiple syntax errors out of the blue with ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not a ruby on rails developer so this might be a menial fix. The friend I'm working on with this project is currently unavailable and was hoping someone could help me resolve this issue that sprang up randomly after reboot my VM. No changes to any files, it was just working and after reboot it wasn't. Tried googling to no avail.

Here is the full post from the console:

```
SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected '%'
...er layout:'application', text:%q(<ng-include src="'/drinks/e...
...                               ^
/home/sirtastic/projects/tipsy-web/app/controllers/drinks_controller.rb:67: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...ation', text:%q(<ng-include src="'/drinks/edit.html'"></ng-i...
...                               ^
/home/sirtastic/projects/tipsy-web/app/controllers/drinks_controller.rb:67: syntax error, unexpected '<'
...ude src="'/drinks/edit.html'"></ng-include>)
...                               ^
/home/sirtastic/projects/tipsy-web/app/controllers/drinks_controller.rb:67: unterminated regexp meets end of file:
  app/controllers/drinks_controller.rb:67:in `'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `constantize'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:59:in `controller'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:38:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'



Started POST "/__better_errors/6570466af1f32e70/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-24 16:12:23 -0800
```

Line 67 in drinks_controller.rb:

```
render layout:'application', text:%q(<ng-include src="'/drinks/edit.html'"></ng-include>)
```

Comment: I would check if the `%` is in fact some strange unicode character and not `U+0025` (the real percent sign).

Comment: @max, would SHIFT+5 be appropriate way to apply the `%`?

Comment: On most keyboards - yes

Comment: @max okay, didn't fix it. Thanks though

Comment: Ah, if you look at the stack track you can see `unterminated regexp meets end of file:` - it seems that there is regular expression which is not closed somewhere. If its not in the controller action check in the model where they are commonly used for validation.

Comment: do you just need a space between text and the % symbole "text: %q.."? did a quick check in rails console and that seemed to help

Comment: @MikeK. That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MikeK. Actually it allowed the page to load the template but all the content/etc was missing.